# Subprocess returns error code 1 when trying to docx to pdf convert via libreoffice

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, libreoffice

I am trying to convet docx to pdf with libreoffice from python, when I run this command in the shell it works fine:

```
libreoffice5.4 --invisible --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /var/some/folder/  /var/other_folder/file.docx
```

S.O.= Linux
Python 2.7
When I try to run the same command from python using

```
subprocess (call, check_call, check_output, Popen)
```

it returns

> return with error (code 1): None

This is part of my code:

```
        command = [
            'libreoffice5.4',
            '--invisible',
            '--headless',
            '--convert-to',
            'pdf:writer_pdf_Export',
            '--outdir',
            'var/folder',
            'file_merge.docx'
        ]

        try:
            process = subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
              logging.info("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
```

Comment: Did you check if you filled all variables to your subprocess-call correctly? My guess would be one of then is `None`. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are doing including all variables/calls/exact code you use.

Comment: Why `shell=True`? It contradicts passing the `command` as list, and it's unnecessary to put a shell between your process and the one you start.

Comment: Are you trying to run this inside a container? I have run into this same issue when it is containerized. I didn't look into it too much, but my guess is that it is docker/containerd limiting the amount of child processes